# Limit two loops in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two different loops that I use on the same view of my rails app, I know how to limit the output for one of them, eg .take(6), .limit(6) etc, but my problem is that because two loops that loop the same variable but in different ways, the limit on one them (and everything else i seemed to try) limits the output of both of the loops and not each one individually. for instance, when I have .take(6), instead of taking the 6 from each different loop it takes 6 together from both loops. It might be clearer with my code:

```
<% @steppy = Steppy.order('created_at DESC')%>

<% @steppy.limit(6).each do |steppy| %>

    <% if steppy.goal.present? %>
        <%= link_to steppy do%>
            <div>       
                <div>
                    <li class="front_panel_new" style="list-style-type: square;">How to become <%= steppy.goal.indefinite_article %> <%= truncate(steppy.goal.capitalize, :length => 150) %></li>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>  
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<% @steppy.each do |steppy| %>
  <% if steppy.ask.present? %>

          <div>       
              <div>
                <%= link_to steppy do%>
                  <li class="front_panel_new" style="list-style-type: square;">How to become  <%= steppy.ask.indefinite_article %>  <%= truncate(steppy.ask.capitalize, :length => 150) %></li>
                <% end %> 
              </div>
          </div>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I need them to have their own separate limit of 6 each.

Comment: Are you running database queries from your view?

Comment: yes I am running them

Comment: is `steppy.ask` a column or a reference to another model?

Comment: it is a column same as goal

Comment: @user2472480 from [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html): _"An important distinction to make is that it is the **controller**, not the view, where information is collected. The view should just display that information."_

Comment: yea i understand, but im not collecting any information im just displaying it in different ways, if there is a better way of doing that im just not aware of it. Im displaying the same table just from different columns if that makes sense.

Comment: He means collecting it from the database - You retrieve the data from the database in the controller, and display it on the view. 

It's not really related to your question, but it's infinitely easier to read and understand as pure ruby, along with better practice.

Comment: What everyone is trying to say is that it's not a good practice to have database queries in your views. Your `@steppy` variable should be created in your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logic problem here, see this code:

```
# controller
@steppies_having_ask = Steppy.where("ask IS NOT NULL AND ask != ''").order('created_at DESC').limit(6)
@steppies_having_goal = Steppy.where('goal IS NOT NULL AND goal != ''').order('created_at DESC').limit(6)

# view
@steppies_having_goal.each do |steppy|
  # display your steppy without testing `if steppy.goal.present?`
end

@steppies_having_ask.each do |steppy|
  # display your steppy without testing `if steppy.ask.present?`    
end
```

---

What is the logic problem you have?

- You get 6 records from the DB and loop on it,
- Then you display the record **only if** it has a value for the `ask` attribute (or `goal`)

What if the 6 records have no value for `ask` (or `goal`)? -> It would display nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for some reason that didnt seem to work, it just gives me 3 altogether now, one from the first loop and 2 from the second

Comment: Are you aware of your if statement that could influence a lot on the records? `if steppy.goal.present?` you display a div, if not you do nothing -> That's maybe why there is one record on top and 2 at the bottom. I'll update my answer with a better logic for this

Comment: the if statement is really there to just discriminate between ones that have goal or asks, but there are enough of them to fill up 6

Comment: But do you understand that if the first 6 elements of your `@steppy` variable does not have a `steppy.goal.present?` it won't show anything? Your code does not make sense, you should define the presence condition directly in the Query, not in the loop

Comment: ahhh i see, ok no i did not know that, i guess thats the problem then that im trying to get around

Comment: @user2472480 I just updated my answer, it might help you. If not, please tell me exactly what you want (something like *"6 first records with goal, and then the same records display their Ask div if they have one"*)

Comment: this looks like it, im trying to implement it just a question, because this is present in my application.html.erb, where in my controller would i be putting the queries in then? because now im getting "Association named 'goal' was not found;" error, which is strange

Comment: You can eventually put it in the view for now. How did you define the relation Steppy - Ask ? And Steppy - Goal ? I thought it would be `steppy belongs_to :goal` and `steppy belongs_to :ask`

Comment: goal and ask are just columns of steppy, so i have "attr_accessible :ask, :goal"

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to fit your Model's structure

Comment: Hey thanks, yeah i managed to get it down to this as well, lastly i removed the if code from the loops as well, (as why would i need it now), now goals loop works but for some reason ask does not, and give me: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: for this line of code: " <li class="front_panel_new" style="list-style-type: square;">How to become  <%= steppy.ask.indefinite_article %>  <%= truncate(steppy.ask.capitalize, :length => 150) %></li>"

Comment: I added an extra condition in the query: `.where("ask IS NOT NULL AND ask != ''")` It might solve your nil pointer exception.

Comment: thanks a lot! that seemed to fix it, could you explain why that extra condition worked? also how can i organize this query by date created now?

Comment: I added an `order by` clause ; The extra condition makes sure we don't retrieve records with an empty value for `ask` (or `goal`). Because an empty string **is not** equal to `NULL`, this is the reason why `ask IS NOT NULL` was not sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Works ok for me.
Try using take instead of limit perhaps?

```
steppy = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
steppy.take(2).each do |s|
   puts "first loop #{s}"
end

steppy.take(6).each do |s|
   puts "second loop #{s}"
end
```

Produces

```
first loop 1
first loop 2
second loop 1
second loop 2
second loop 3
second loop 4
second loop 5
second loop 6
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.each_slice(x)`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) is good too, except it won't fix your problem (just provide blocks for the same var):

```
steppy.each_slice(6) do |block|
    for item in block do
       # outputs each item
    end
end
```